# Load reCaptcha V3 after user consent (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, cookies, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am trying to implement a small "cookie-checker". I don't want the js of Google reCaptcha be loaded before the user gave explicit consent.

My problem is that when the js library is loaded after everything else, i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: grecaptcha.ready is not a function
```

This is the code where i call the grecaptcha functions.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const contactForm = document.getElementById("contact-form");
    const submitButton = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
    const recaptchaResponseInput = document.getElementById("recaptcha_response");

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha.execute('################', { action: 'submit' }).then(function (token) {
            recaptchaResponseInput.value = token;
            contactForm.submit();
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

And this is the code where i load the recaptcha library:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const cookieBanner = document.getElementById("cookie-banner");
        const acceptCookiesButton = document.getElementById("accept-cookies");
        const contactform = document.getElementById("contactform");

        acceptCookiesButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // save consent
            localStorage.setItem("cookieConsent", "true");

            // load reCAPTCHA-skript
            $.getScript("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=##############");

            // Cookie-Banner ausblenden
            cookieBanner.style.display = "none";
            contactform.style.display = "block";
        });
    });
```

I know loading the library works correctly, because the little reCAPTCHA icons appears on the down right side of my website, when it is loaded.
Is there another, better way of blocking the JavaScript-Script until a user has given permission?

Edit:
I get the same problem with this:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const cookieBanner = document.getElementById("cookie-banner");
    const acceptCookiesButton = document.getElementById("accept-cookies");
    const contactform = document.getElementById("contactform");

    acceptCookiesButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // save consent
        localStorage.setItem("cookieConsent", "true");

        // Load reCAPTCHA-skript with onload callback
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=#################";
        script.onload = function() {
            // reCAPTCHA library loaded
            contactform.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                    grecaptcha.execute('#####################', { action: 'submit' }).then(function (token) {
                        const recaptchaResponseInput = document.getElementById("recaptcha_response");
                        recaptchaResponseInput.value = token;
                        contactform.submit();
                });
            });

            // Hide cookie banner and show contact form
            cookieBanner.style.display = "none";
            contactform.style.display = "block";
        };
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
});
</script>
```